# Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to [0, 1]$ is known, how to sample $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(x)$ follows uniform distribution?

Tags: sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, random-generation

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is known, where evaluation and gradient computation is easy. How can I sample $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f_x \in \mathbb{R}$ follows uniform distribution? Is there any good sampling algorithm for such problem?

My current workaround is, splitting $[0, 1]$ into many bins with equal fulfill sample number `n_{fill}` for each bin, and then, sampling randomly from a prior-distribution until all bins are fulfilled with $n_{fill}$ samples. This is fairly easy to implement, but bit costly.

Comment: In general, you first need to know that $f$ is surjective. Then restrict it to a subset $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ so that the restriction $f|_X$ is even bijective. Then invert this to obtain $(f|_X)^{-1}$. Now sample $y\sim U[0,1]$ and use $x=(f|_X)^{-1}(y)$. You may be able to be more specific if you know additional properties of $f$, right now your $f$ could be very pathological indeed.

Comment: @Stephan Even more generally and simply, draw a uniform value $U$ and -- using any procedure you like, deterministic or random -- find a value $x$ for which $f(x)=U.$  How that $x$ is found depends, of course, on how $f$ is represented and computed, which is why this question needs more details to have any more specific answer.